# What am I missing in the code? Is it the import or is it extra line of code?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

```
package com.example.myapplication2

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.ImageView

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       when {
            intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
               when {
                 intent.type == PLAIN_TEXT_MIME -> handleSendText(intent)
                 intent.type?.startsWith(MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME) == true -> 
         handleSendImage(intent) // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE -> {
            when {
                intent.type?.startsWith(MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME) == true -> handleSendMultipleImages(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
       val textView.text = it // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

private fun handleSendImage(intent: Intent) {
    (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {
       val first_ImageView.setImageURI(it)// Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

private fun handleSendMultipleImages(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)?.let {
        first_imageView.setImageURI(it(0) as? Uri)
        second_imageView.setImageURI(it(1) as? Uri)// Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val PLAIN_TEXT_MIME = "text/plain"
    private const val MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME = "image/"
    }
   }
```

Error message I received:

```
Local extension properties are not allowed
Local extension properties are not allowed
This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialized
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
Unresolved reference: first_imageView
<html>Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:<br/>public operator fun &lt;T, R&gt; DeepRecursiveFunction&lt;TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)&gt;.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin
Unresolved reference: second_imageView
<html>Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:<br/>public operator fun &lt;T, R&gt; DeepRecursiveFunction&lt;TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)&gt;.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin
Unused import directive
Unused import directive
Variable 'text' is never used
'when' with subject should be used
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here's the problem

```
 val first_ImageView.setImageURI(it)
```

You need to delete the 'val'

EDIT: Just like [Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) mentioned you need to bind the layout to your MainActivity (but only if these TextViews are actually in your activity_main.xml):

Add this field to your activity:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

And in onCreate() add this:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Then if you want to invoke setImageUri() on a TextView do this:

```
binding.yourTextView.setImageURI(it)
```

Alternatively you could just write:

```
val first_ImageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.first_ImageView)
```

And then perform operations on the ImageView that was found

EDIT2:

You need to change you methods to this:

```
private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
       findViewById<View>(R.id.textView)?.text = it // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

    private fun handleSendImage(intent: Intent) {
        (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {
           findViewById<View>(R.id.first_ImageView)?.setImageURI(it)// Update UI to reflect image being shared
        }
    }
    
    private fun handleSendMultipleImages(intent: Intent) {
        intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)?.let {
            findViewById<View>(R.id.first_ImageView)?.setImageURI(it(0) as? Uri)
            findViewById<View>(R.id.second_imageView)?.setImageURI(it(1) as? Uri)// Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its more than this-  he has no firstImageView ever created.  He needs a private val first_ImageView in the class.  Or he needs to use ViewBinding, which seems like what he wants

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused. Where would I put the val first_ImageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.first_ImageView). Also, would I do that with textView and second_ImageView as well

Comment: I edited the answer again to make it clearer where you need to apply the changes

Comment: Still running the same problem

Comment: Do I need to "create id value resource "textView"? Does have to do with my widget?

Comment: Could you post the .xml file with your TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

Without View Bindings.
You need to define views in your activity file and assign their values after setContentView method then you can use it to update your UI.

```
`package com.example

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.ImageView

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private lateinit var firstImage: ImageView;
  private lateinit var secondImage: ImageView;
  private lateinit var textView: TextView;

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
    firstImage = findViewById(R.id.firstImage)
    secondImage = findViewById(R.id.secondImage)
    when {
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
            when {
                intent.type == PLAIN_TEXT_MIME -> handleSendText(intent)
                intent.type?.startsWith(MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME) == true ->
                    handleSendImage(intent) // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE -> {
            when {
                intent.type?.startsWith(MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME) == true -> 
handleSendMultipleImages(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
        textView.text = it // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

private fun handleSendImage(intent: Intent) {
    (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {
        firstImage.setImageURI(it)// Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

private fun handleSendMultipleImages(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)?.let {
        firstImage.setImageURI(it[0] as? Uri)
        secondImage.setImageURI(it[1] as? Uri)// Update UI to reflect multiple 
images being shared
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val PLAIN_TEXT_MIME = "text/plain"
    private const val MEDIA_IMAGE_MIME = "image/"
  }
}
`
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/secondImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can use ViewBindings  to remove the findViewById calls.
[https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding]

Comment: Thanks. I figure out the problem already.